# Send C# Assembly/DLL Over Network?

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, .net-assembly

My goal is to have my server send an assembly over the network at runtime of some classes that the client will need. This way the client DLL never needs to be updated at all. I was wondering if there is a better way to do this then just sending the full DLL file? I am using a TCP connection.

For anybody who is worried about the security of this choice, we are on a wired only local network where nobody has access, but trusted clients.

Comment: but to call / download the assembly from service also u need atleast one assembly as client right?? agreed?? if so then i will say way posting the assembly? use wcf / remoting to call the method and get the result over the network

Comment: I do have a backend DLL which will pretty much never be changed and is responsible for sending/receiving messages as well as client/server start up. I don't know much about WCF, but I'm currently using protobufs to do communication. I have an initial message that contains the byte[] of the serialized assembly. The main question is how to serialize in the smallest most effective form?

Comment: I can tell u what approach I have used once. that was a server(local network server) from where I will get the updated dll. I was having one web asmx service from which first i get the version of the file on the server. if the version match with the version on client. i proceed to run the wpf form, but if version not same i download the dll from server to client and save at the same location on old file in client then run the wpf application.  hope it can work in ur scenario also

Comment: I'll look into it. I'm kind of questionable on some of the details, but thanks for the input!

Comment: Wow, well that could definitely work and it doesn't look too difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you're describing is the problem that ClickOnce is designed to solve.  From the [ClickOnce Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx):

> ClickOnce is a deployment technology that enables you to create self-updating Windows-based applications that can be installed and run with minimal user interaction. Visual Studio provides full support for publishing and updating applications deployed with ClickOnce technology if you have developed your projects with Visual Basic and Visual C#.

One of the most important aspects of this is security.  For example, how to verify that the assembly is safe to run, that the assembly is from the right source, etc.  A major benefit of to *not* building a custom implementation is that you're using industry standard and vetted mechanisms.  ClickOnce uses certificates.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I actually got my custom one working since I asked, but this is probably the best answer for future development or anyone else looking to do this kind of thing.